# Folium - plugins.HeatMapWithTime no longer produces an output

Tags: python, heat-map, folium

I have been creating Heat Maps with a Time dimension using both test data and my own datasets using the Folium libraries in Python. I am using Python 3.5 to do this, and the results have been good.

I have been away and one returning I have noticed that these scripts no longer produce a result that is viewable.

The scripts run without error, and the outputs open with the correct basemaps, however, the heatmap and the time sliders are no longer visible.

At first I thought it was the data I was using, but I have a test script taken from Git that I have been using to test some formatting and displays, but this no longer works.

https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/blob/master/tests/plugins/test_heat_map_withtime.py

```
import folium
import folium.plugins as plugins
import numpy as np
import webbrowser

from datetime import datetime, timedelta

np.random.seed(3141592)
initial_data = (
    np.random.normal(size=(100, 2)) * np.array([[1, 1]]) +
    np.array([[48, 5]])
)

move_data = np.random.normal(size=(100, 2)) * 0.01

data = [(initial_data + move_data * i).tolist() for i in range(100)]


weight = 1  # default value
for time_entry in data:
    for row in time_entry:
        row.append(weight)

print (data)

time_index = [
    (datetime.now() + k * timedelta(1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for
    k in range(len(data))
]

print (len(time_index))

m = folium.Map([48., 5.], tiles='stamentoner', zoom_start=6)

hm = plugins.HeatMapWithTime(
    data,
    index=time_index,
    auto_play=True,
    max_opacity=0.3
)

hm.add_to(m)
m.save (r'c:\temp\Time.html')
webbrowser.open(r'c:\temp\Time.html')
```

Has something changed with the Folium libraries / anything?
I thought maybe it was a firewall issue at work, but even going offline / using a connection outside of work produces the same result:

A Basemap, with no data to display.

Comment: Hey, I've upgraded to folium 0.10.1 and still having the problem where I see only base map. Any suggestions? I've ran your code and it still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I just checked and I am still on 0.10.1 and the above codes works. What version of Python you running?

Comment: It worked after replacing `ttps://rawcdn.githack.com/socib/Leaflet.TimeDimension/master/dist/leaflet.timedimension.min.js`
with
`https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet-timedimension@1.1.0/dist/leaflet.timedimension.min.js` Inside heat_map_withtime.py file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has been an update in December 2019 upgrade folium and it should return, mine have today on doing pip install folium --upgrade

Comment: Upgraded and my heatmaps are working again...